# Cannot establish connection to a SQL server running in Docker container using Project Tye

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, docker, tye

I'm fairly new to the whole concept of the microservice architecture, but I have managed to create a simple proof of concept application, which consists of 1 Blazor server-side front-end, 6 microservices, which are all .net 6 WEB APIs and are currently using an InMemory database and they all seed mock data inside of their DBs on startup.
I'm using Project Tye to run all projects simultaneously and to easily deploy them to a local kubernetes cluster.

Now I would like to migrate from aforementioned InMemory databases for each microservice to a sqlserver database.

Tye allows to run an image as a dependency in the tye.yaml file and setting environment variables from the configuration, which is then passed through Tye's VS extension for configuration as a ConnectionString.

Here is the snippet from it regarding one sqlserver:

```
- name: sqlserver-videoteka
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest 
  env:
  - name: SA_PASSWORD
    value: "M!cr0s3rv!ce"
  - name: ACCEPT_EULA
    value: 'Y'
  volumes:
  - name: videoteka-storage
    target: /var/opt/mssql
  bindings:
  - port: 9634
    connectionString: Server=${host}:${port};Database=VideotekaDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=sa;Password=${env:SA_PASSWORD};
```

And then in the microservice's Program.cs file I add these 2 lines:

```
connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlserver-videoteka");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<VideotekaDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

So then I attempt to run **tye run** and I check the logs from the mentioned microservice and this is what I'm met with:

```
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]:E:\OceniFilm\Videoteka.API\bin\Debug\net6.0\Videoteka.API.exe
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: CONNECTION STRING: Server=localhost:9634;Database=VideotekaDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=sa;Password=M!cr0s3rv!ce;
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: Entity Framework Core 6.0.3 initialized 'VideotekaDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.3' with options: None
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: [PrepareDb] Migration unsuccessful: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: An error occurred using the connection to database 'VideotekaDB' on server 'localhost:9634'.
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Videoteka.API.Data.VideotekaDbContext'.
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): The network path was not found.
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
[videoteka-api_ae1ba91d-5]: at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
```

As I understood Tye's configuration, it would create the image of the sql server and use my variables for the credentials, no?

Would a separate sqlserver container need to be running on my machine? But then why would it pull the image and create a container?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: CER solved it for me regarding the **tye run**, but when running **tye deploy**, the sqlserver gets skipped?

[image: this]

this happens right at the end of deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be 2 issues:

1. Your `bindings` section should include `containerPort:1433` to map to `9643`. See [tye schema](https://github.com/dotnet/tye/blob/main/docs/reference/schema.md#containerport-string).
2. Re: `connectionstring`. SQL Server delimiter between host and port is *not* a colon (`:`), it's a comma (`,`). e.g. `localhost,9643`.

Comment: That worked! I completely overlooked that schema option and haven't seen it being used anywhere else. I kindly thank you very much, you've saved me countless of hours.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/7LOZlgUWycdb this happens right at the end of deployment. The sqlserver container just gets skipped for some reason.. it doesn't do that when ran with **tye run**. Do you maybe have an idea why that happens?

Comment: I assume you're deploying to a Kubernetes cluster?  If so, Tye will NOT deploy "dependency" containers to K8s automatically.  They must be `apply`ed to K8s first.  See this [example](https://github.com/dotnet/tye/blob/ad3f692d53ab1dd5bca5c2508d47c287777a7e40/docs/tutorials/hello-tye/02_add_redis.md#deploying-redis).